# Galerkin Orthogonality in this FEM?

Tags: inequality, hilbert-spaces, integral-inequality, finite-element-method

Problem

[image]

Galerkin orthogonality is

[image]

but I am not sure if it is in the right form.

**How can you use this orthogonality here?**
I think I should expand the last inequality first somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left\| u -u_{h}\right\|_{E}^{2}
&= a(u-v_{h} + v_{h} -u_{h}, u-u_{h}) \\
&= a(u-v_{h}, u - u_{h})  + a(v_{h}-u_{h}, u-u_{h}) \\
&= a(u-v_{h}, u - u_{h})  \\
&\le \left\| u -v_{h}\right\|_{E}\left\| u-u_{h}\right\|_{E}
\end{align}
$a(v_{h}-u_{h}, u-u_{h})  = 0$ by ''Galerkin orthogonality'', as $v_{h} -u_{h} \in V_{h}$.

In particular, 
\begin{align}
\left\| u -u_{h}\right\|_{E} \le \left\| u -v_{h}\right\|_{E}
\end{align}
for all $v_{h} \in V_{h}$, which implies the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very elegant way of showing this by adding zero to the left side.